# Finding desirabilities and probabilities in Jeffrey's Logic of Decision

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, probability

I'm trying to solve problem 16 (Ch. 5) of Jeffrey's Logic of Decision.
The problem says:

> Suppose that A and B are pairwise incompatible propositions, and
>   suppose that the preference ranking is as follows:
>
> A,B,G
>
> T
>
> ¬G, ¬(A∨B)
>
> ¬A, ¬B
>
> Suppose that *des G* = 1 and *des T* = 0
>
> b) Assuming that *des ¬G* = -2, find *des ¬A*, *prob A*, *prob B*, *prob G*.

My attempt to solve it:

By (5-5) *prob G* = 1 / (1 - (*des G* / *des ¬G*))

So *prob G* = 1 / (1 - (1 / -2)) = **2/3**

By problem 11, if A and B are ranked together but not with T, then ***prob A* = *prob B*** iff ¬A and ¬B are ranked together, which is the case.

By (5-6) *des ¬(A∨B)* = -(*prob A∨B* / *prob ¬(A∨B)*) * *des A∨B* = -2, since it's ranked together with ¬G.

By (5-2) *des A∨B* = (*prob A* * *des A* + *prob B* * *des B*) / (*prob A* + *prob B*) = 1, since *prob A* = *prob B*, and both *des* A and *des* B are equal to 1.

So, by substitution:

-2 = -(*prob A∨B* / *prob ¬(A∨B)*) * (*prob A* * *des A* + *prob B* * *des B*) / (*prob A* + *prob B*)

=  -(*prob A∨B* / *prob ¬(A∨B)*) * 1.

That's as far as I get.

I've also tried to solve for ¬(A∨B), since it is logically equivalent to ¬A¬B, with equation (5-1)(e) [page 81](https://books.google.it/books?id=geJ-SwTcmyEC&pg=PA76#v=onepage&q&f=false) but it doesn't get me anywhere.

What am I missing?

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks for your time and consideration.

NOTE: It's not homework. It's just me trying to understand the theory.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

As we sorted out in the comments below, everything until your conclusion *prob(A)=prob(B)* is correct. 
So I will start there.

You have shown:

> By (5-2) des A∨B = (prob A * des A + prob B * des B) / (prob A + prob B) = 1, since prob A = prob B.

But to apply (5-2), one has to show that prob(A∨B)≠0: if this were the case, then *0=prob(A∨B)des(A∨B)+prob¬(A∨B)des¬(A∨B)=des¬(A∨B)*, which contradicts the ranking of *¬(A∨B)*.

*des ¬(A∨B)=-2*, since it is ranked together with *¬G*. 
This allows us to compute *prob(A∨B)* via 
*prob¬(A∨B)=1/(1-(des¬(A∨B)/des(A∨B)))=1/3*. Since *A* and *B* are mutually exclusive, and we already know that *prob(A)=prob(B)* we have *prob(A∨B)=2⋅prob(A)* and via 
*1-1/3=1-prob¬(A∨B)=prob(A∨B)=2⋅prob(A)* we conclude *prob(A)=1/3*.

Now to compute *des(¬A)*, use *prob(A)=1/(1-(des(A)/des(¬A)))*. 
Solving this for *des(¬A)* yields *des(¬A)=-1/2*.

**That does not fit the assumed order**:

That seems to be an error with the exercise: 
If *des(¬A)=-prob(A)/prob(¬A)*1 = -prob(A)/(1-prob(A))≤-2*, one can conclude *prob(A)≥ 2/3*. With the same argument *prob(B)≥ 2/3*. But *A* and *B* are supposed to be mutually incompatible, and the sum of their probabilities would exceed *1*, which is impossible.

Thanks for pointing out all the errors.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. Thank you. But, I've been studying it and there's something that doesn't fit. The problem states that ¬G is ranked above ¬A, therefore des ¬G > des ¬A. However, in the answer des ¬A > des ¬G (-1/2 > -2).

Comment: That is a good point. Assuming that problem 11 is really applicable (and it should be, if it says *exactly* what you have written there), the only cause of trouble I can see is (5-6). So what exactly does (5-6) say? More input would be helpful. Just to be sure, *prob* means probability, right?

Comment: Yes, _prob_ is probability. (5-6) says this exactly [page 86](https://books.google.it/books?id=geJ-SwTcmyEC&lpg=PA76&hl=it&pg=PA86#v=onepage&q&f=false): "if _des_ T=0 and _des_ X ≠ 1, we have (5-6) _des_ ¬X = -(_prob_ X / prob ¬X) (_des_ X)."

Comment: Then (5-6) is simply not applicable here. By the way, you used (5-6) nevertheless in your reasoning without showing that this assumption is satisfied. There might be an error as well. I will look into it when I get home and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: In relation to page 86, I found a mistake in the book. The assumption of (5-6) is not that _des_ X ≠ 1 but that _prob_ X ≠ 1, which makes more sense. This is clear in the 1965 edition of the book.